# How to set the expiration date for Dropbox file URL's

Tags: java, dropbox

In Dropbox we can able to see "Add an expiration date to this link?" after using the share button. So I don't want to use that one, I want to change the expiration date for that particular file through programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`/modify_shared_link_settings`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-modify_shared_link_settings).

Comment: for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {  
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateString = "2020-12-12";
Date dateObject;
 dateObject = sdf.parse(dateString); 
 DbxUrlWithExpiration e = dbxClient.createTemporaryDirectUrl(child.path); 
DbxUrlWithExpiration exp = new DbxUrlWithExpiration(url, dateObject);
System.out.println(" URL "+exp.url);
 }

Comment: @sreekanth_p That code has nothing to do with my answer.