# DropBox: how to set unexpiration links for the dropbox url's

Tags: java, dropbox

Right now i am using basic Dropbox api. with this app can we able to set the expiration date for url's why beacause the link is exist only for 6 hours after this time it is giving error.
or we have to use/purchase the bussiness api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the expiration date for Dropbox file URL's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237123/how-to-set-the-expiration-date-for-dropbox-file-urls)

Answer (score 0):

[Dropbox Source] This is possible using the /sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings endpoint
to set the expiration date

**Check the documentation**

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings

Comment: actually i am using basic dropbox api for this it is showing like this for expiration settings                                                                                                                                Add an expiry date to this link? YES/NO      herein this case can't able to change the expiration date

Comment: Yes, check the link.

Comment: if i want to change that settings from java program what i need to do